# How to increasing delay between each retry of a failed download

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job that receives messages from Kafka. For some of the messages a file is downloaded from an external source.
If for some reason the external source is not responding the job retries for some few times.

If it still can’t download the file I like to back of for and hour and then try again. If it still fails it should double the delay and retry again after 2 hours and so on.

What would be a good way to implement this using Kafka and Spark?

One thought is to post the info of the failed downloads back to a new topic on Kafka adding the time of when it next time should retry
Then have a batch job running every 10 min which receives the info of failed downloads.
The Job should then do the following:
1. for all downloads where the retry time has not passed the message is reposted to kafka.
2. for all downloads where the retry time has passed it retry the download and if it succed all is good but if it fails the info is posted back to kafka with a new retry time.

One thing I don’t like with this solution is that it receives and posts the messages that where the delay has not jet passed resulting in more than necessary traffic.

I like to get any pros and cons regarding this solution or if there are better ways to implement this.

Thanks Sebastian